# How to generate a CMake file from MSBuild solution?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I need to provide source code with CMake files by the end of the week. I am too stupid to understand CMake in such a short period of time, though the code itself is simplistic, I am only familiar with Visual Studio environment and its settings for visual c++ projects. Is there a way to generate CMake solution from Visual C++ solution? Google results are cluttered with results for reverse process.

Comment: "How to generate a CMake file from MSBuild solution?" - it's usually the other way round..

Comment: "I am too stupid to " is a bad attitude. Anything can be learned if you are determined to! Anyways, define the term "CMake solution" first (CMake generates files for the appropriate build system, it isn't really a solution in the way you're thinking of it).

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I don't know much, but from what every guide on CMake says I need a number of CMake.txt files (one for each directory or something like that) and CMake.json which contains... something. If I had time I wouldn't bother with this question, but I've got numerous things to actually do, instead of learning some god forsaken technology I will avoid for the rest of my life.